# Treating lines wrapped with `linebreak` as separate lines

Tags: wrapping, line-breaks

I know the `linebreak` option can be used to soft-wrap lines within vim (without inserting any newlines into the file being edited).

However, I often need to navigate over long lines that have been wrapped. I am aware that <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> allow moving up and down display lines, rather than real lines in the file, but I need to be able to achieve this behaviour with other motions like <kbd>$</kbd> (which should go to the end of the current display line, rather than going to the real end, which may be several display lines down).

Being able to manipulate display lines with linewise-visual mode would also be extremely useful. Is there any succinct way to achieve this? I know creating mappings, such as `0 g0`, `$ g$` is an option, but I want this to work with **all** motions that deal in some way with lines, and making that many mappings would be quite inconvenient.

Comment: You mean mapping the non-`g` motions to the `g` ones right? Such as `map j gj` and `map $ g$` etc. correct? There are really not many more commands that work differently when wrap is on... Which commands do you think you might be missing?

Comment: @filbranden as far as I can tell, actions like `dd`, `yy` do not have an equivalent. Not all motions can just be prefixed with `g`. There is no `gy`, and `gd` does something totally different. My problem is primarily when I want to use visual line mode to select a couple of lines (for deletion, yanking, etc), because `V` would select all of the "lines", rather than the current one.

Comment: So `dd` should do what, exactly?

Comment: I feel like the right solution for many of these cases is to use hooks that will split long lines when reading files and joining them back only when saving. So you see multiple lines in Vim (and you can edit line by line) but when you're done editing it's saved with long lines... I have a similar case where I should use something like that. What's the format of the file for which you'd like to use something like that? (Mine is Markdown...)

Comment: @filbranden I'm editing markdown files, yes.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `dd` should do something like `g^dg$`. The problem is that this needs to play nicely with `d`'s behaviour as an operator, e.g. `3dd`, highlighting lines and deleting them with `Vd`, etc. I'm beginning to think this might be too complicated to manage without a huge/complex plugin or actually editing vim's source.